# Return records based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

The value for @c is a parameter set by the user.  If there is a value I would like to query for Cars with that condition.  If @c is nil I would like to return all of the Car records.

```
     @cars = Car.where('car_type = ?', @c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a basic check to see if `@c` is blank:

```
@cars = @c.blank? ? Car.scoped : Car.where('car_type = ?', @c)
```